# Return to previous mode in Emacs

Tags: emacs

Is there a key binding to quit a mode and return to the previous mode in emacs?
For example suppose I entered line number mode using the following command:

```
Alt+x linum-mode
```

How can I quickly disable this mode and return to the mode which I was in before (not using the same command again)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why wouldn't you want to use the same command again?

<kbd>M-x</kbd><kbd>M-p</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>

It doesn't get much simpler than that.

*Edit:* You can repeat <kbd>M-p</kbd> in that sequence to step back further in the command history, and you can *search* the command history with <kbd>M-x</kbd><kbd>C-r</kbd>.

Also, when you disable a minor mode you're not "returning to the mode you were in before"; you're just disabling one (of many) minor modes which are all active at the same time.

Tangentially, the concept of "returning to the mode you were in before" *could* apply to major modes (as there's only ever one active major mode in a given buffer), but strictly speaking there's no notion of 'disabling' a major mode -- only of 'enabling' the one you wish to change to -- so to 'toggle' between two major modes, you would need to call them alternately.

Comment: OK, perhaps this is a bit faster than typing the same command again if there are not other items in history after the mode command. ;)

Comment: Even if there are, note that you need only repeat `M-p` until you get back to the command in question. And if you have to search so far back that it's no longer faster than typing the command manually... well, I'm not sure it's reasonable to expect there to be some kind of hot-key to "undo that one thing I did 15 minutes ago; you know the one I mean" :) however you *can* also search the history with `M-x C-r`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "your comment could apply to major modes."  However, it is worth noting that repeating a major-mode command will not toggle back to the major-mode you were in before.  I would suspect that it is a very rare instance when you wish to toggle between major modes though.

Comment: nispio: True, I didn't word that very well. I just meant the *concept* of "returning to the previous mode" doesn't make sense for minor modes, but could make sense for major modes (even though, as you rightly point out, you can't *toggle* major modes the way you can with minor modes). I've updated the answer to clarify those comments.

Answer (score 1):

Just repeat the same command: `M-x linum-mode`. Such minor-mode commands are toggles: on/off.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>C-x z</kbd> calls `repeat` - repeat last command.
Repeatedly calling a minor-mode enables/disables it.

One more way to do it is with `smex`: the last command
that you called with <kbd>M-x</kbd> kinda sticks around.
So you can enable `linum-mode` with `smex`, do a bunch of editing
with usual shortcuts and then disable `linum-mode` with
<kbd>M-x RET</kbd>.

Comment: That helps here only if no other command was used since enabling the mode. Yes, @coffeMug said "quickly", but this requires that `C-x z` be done before anything else.

Answer (score 0):

A solution might follow the path `kill-ring-save` works: store the modes being active as current-modes-listing in a previous-modes-ring.

The code needed therefor exists basically inside `describe-mode`, see upward from "Enabled minor modes" - respective for the major mode.

Then a hook should check if `this-command` has "-mode" in it's name. If yes, check, if current modes-listing equals  car of previous-modes-ring. If not, add new setting.

Finally write a command which sets current modes according to selected listing from previous-modes-ring.